# How to insert data into a B-Tree of order 3 ?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, b-tree

I want to store these data into a B-Tree of order 3 (10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90) and my result is 
[image: B-Tree]

and It does not match with my book's result. 
Is it ok? 
thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by

> Is it ok?

There are two possible interpretations:

1. Does the tree conform to the structural properties of an order-3 b-tree?
2. Could the tree be obtained by a specific sequence of operations?

In this case, the answer to 1. is true, but the answer to 2. is false. If you run the insertion algorithm for each stage, e.g., you will see that the leftmost bottom key is 10, with no right children, and no further insertions of the sequence shown will change that.

---

To see the specific result of the sequence of inserts you specified, you can use this [very cool interactive demo](https://s3.amazonaws.com/learneroo/visual-algorithms/BTree.html).

Comment: thanks and actually I meant  no#2. can You show me the final tree after sequential insertion of the data ?

Comment: @HelGalib Added a link to a very cool interactive demo, which allows you to do what you asked.

Comment: Wow thats great!! Thanks a lot !